# use custom core data persistent store for getting data via webservices?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios4

Is this a good idea?  When is it a good idea, and when is it bad?

Just heard about this in one of the WWDC videos, and I don't quite understand why would one want to do it this way.  Seems complicated and I cannot see the benefit.

Comment: could you please post the name/year of the WWDC video?

Comment: WWDC 2010 Session 117 @ 35:53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, it would be to totally abstract the data access layer. You'd then be able to access the web service using Core Data fetch request API. You'd also be able to implement caching in the persistent store without affecting the application logic.

Also changing the web service request/response format could potentially only affect the persistent store layer.

I see it can be a benefit for large requests. Since networking is quite expensive in battery life, application should use as less bandwidth as possible so developing a single request sending more information but using Core Data to access only subsets at a time is a good design in my opinion.

Finally, I think Core Data API blends well with major ORM web framework like rails or django for example.

Comment: don't you think Core Data for data through network is overkill? can you see a potential performance problem?  How would one handle network disconnection gracefully? I've not dig into the API but I really wonder the good it brings vs the added complexity (see video, subclassing persistent store.. :S)

Comment: Overkill maybe. But if it means I'll never have to access my data other than using Core Data since all web services is enclosed in persistent store and I can manage disconnection by persisting locally and updating when network is back transparently, it may be worth it. In the application I'm developing, I do not do this and just do the old way and implemented the caching and updating of web service outside but I may be considering it for the next one.

Answer (score 1):

It is complicated and it is meant to show *what* you can do with Core Data.  I personally like to keep server communication separate from the local cache and then update the server based on changes to the local cache.  This means that I use code that listens for save events from Core Data and then updates the server.